# How can we generate flow files using java code in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a way to generate flow files in apache-nifi using java code which i will invoke using ExecuteStreamCommand ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteStreamCommand` starts system command and passes flow file to `STDIN` of this command, then takes `STDOUT` of the command and stores as a content of the flow file.

So, in java you have to write code that reads data from STDIN (System.in) and writes processed data to STDOUT (System.out)

I advice you to check [ExecuteScript groovy examples](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=nifi+groovy+example) because it is a java-based scripting language.

Comment: hey daggett, thanks for your answer. Assume that i have a content stored in string how can i write it to a flow file? System.out.println(str) will display in log files isn't it?

Comment: should be `System.out.println()`

Comment: Thanks a lot daggett, it worked. we have to set `Ignore STDIN` property as true.